# How to force Composer script to load local class instead of global class

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

#### undefined method

(Relevant files linked at the bottom of my question.)

I let Composer run some `post-install-cmd` and `post-update-cmd` scripts. In my script I want to make use of the [`readlink()`](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/components/filesystem.html#readlink) function from `symfony/filesystem`. Inside my projects `/vendor` folder there is the `3.4` version of the filesystem package, fine.

I `use Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem;` at the top of my file.

But whenever I run:

```
$fs = new Filesystem();
$path = '/path/to/some/symlink';
if ($fs->readlink($path)) {
  // code
}
```

I get the following error which tells me I'm calling an undefined method:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
>   Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem::readlink() in
>   /Users/leymannx/Sites/blog/scripts/composer/ScriptHandler.php:160

OK, so I double-checked the class inside my project's `/vendor` folder. This method is there. My IDE points me there. But when I run:

```
$fs = new Filesystem();
get_class_methods($fs);
```

this method is not listed.

#### Which file is it trying to load the method from?

OK, so I tried to check which file it's loading this class from:

```
$fs = new Filesystem();
$a = new \ReflectionClass($fs);
echo $a->getFileName();
```

and that returns me `phar:///usr/local/Cellar/composer/1.7.2/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/filesystem/Filesystem.php` – But why? Why is it taking the package from my Mac's Cellar? That's odd.

But OK, so I thought that's a Homebrew issue, and uninstalled the Homebrew Composer `$ brew uninstall --force composer` and installed it again as PHAR like documented on https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally.

But now it's the same.

```
$fs = new Filesystem();
$a = new \ReflectionClass($fs);
echo $a->getFileName();
```

returns me `phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/filesystem/Filesystem.php`.

But why? Why does it pick up the (outdated) package from my global Composer installation? How can I force my script to use the project's local class and not the one from my global Composer installation?

#### What else?

Initially my `$PATH` contained `/Users/leymannx/.composer/vendor/bin /usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin`. I removed `/Users/leymannx/.composer/vendor/bin` to only return `/usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin`. Still the same.

I also tried setting the following in my `composer.json`. Still the same:

```
"optimize-autoloader": true,
"classmap-authoritative": true,
"vendor-dir": "vendor/",
```

I finally created an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/7708

---

- https://github.com/leymannx/wordpress-project/blob/master/composer.json
- https://github.com/leymannx/wordpress-project/blob/master/scripts/composer/ScriptHandler.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed it by requiring `require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php'` at the top of my script and leaving everything else untouched.

On the [Filesystem Component docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/filesystem.html) page it's also written:

> If you install this component outside of a Symfony application, you must require the `vendor/autoload.php` file in your code to enable the class autoloading mechanism provided by Composer.

Answer (score 1):

This is matter of context where your code is run. If you're executing some method directly in `post-install-cmd` it will be executed inside of Composer's process. It means that it will share all code bundled inside of `composer.phar`. Since you can't have two classes with the same FQN, you can't include another `Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem` in this context.

You can bypass this by running your script inside of separate process. You may create `post-install-cmd.php` file where you do all bootstrapping (like require `vendor/autoload.php`) and call these methods. Then run this file in your `post-install-cmd` hook:

```
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php post-install-cmd.php"
    ]
},
```